Gradle suppress "Unresolved reference:" (Kotlin Multiplatform)
My Kotlin Multiplatform project is built for iOS and Android.
However, with some required cocoapods we have libs referenced in gradle, that exist only on MacOS machines, thus preventing a gradle sync on Windows and Linux machines - even if they would only build Android builds.
The build.gradle.kts file looks like that:
kotlin {

  cocoapods {
     ios.deploymentTarget = config.minIOSVersion.get()
     pod("ourPod") {
       version = libs.versions.ios.ourpod.sdk.get()
       extraOpts += listOf("-compiler-option", "-fmodules")
     }
  }
  ...

This however leads on Windows and Linux machines to the error:
Unresolved reference: cocoapods as well as some other errors like por() etc.
I wrapped the whole thing in a OS check like that
if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_MAC)) { ...

Still though gradle would not need it, the error is still there.
Is there a way to exclude/ignore/suppress these warnings? Since the wrapping line prevents it from being executed I see no need for that. On Windows/Linux I need this code basically commented out. Any
